# formulation of evidence lower bound (ELBO) of the log likelihood

Tags: machine-learning, variational-bayes

Since the evidence lower bound (ELBO) of the log likelihood, $\log p_{\theta}(x)$, is
$$\mathbb{E}_{q_\phi(z|x)} [\log p_\theta(x|z)] - \text{KL}(q_\phi(z|x), p(z)).$$But we can also write the above as
$$\mathbb{E}_{q_\phi(z|x)} [\log p_\theta(x|z) + \log p(z) - \log(q_\phi(z|x)].$$

So, practically, will training a Variational Autoencoders(VAE) using the formulation in the first formulation be the same as the second formulation? Why or why not?

Comment: These are equivalent. It's like asking whether there will be a practical difference between $5x - 5$ and $5(x-1)$.

Comment: But in practice, training a VAE using the first formulation is the same as second formation?

Comment: What are you asking here? They're the same function.